# Order dynamic list of object by common property with pagination

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a several types of objects, which are I get from database, with different models that have common **date** property. I want to sort all this models but pull out data only in the end by pages.

**Problem** is when I add all `IQueryable` models in dynamic list they pull out all data from database and if there hundreds of records it will take a long time.

What I have already done:

1. Created base interface and in models inherited from him.
2. Added all models in dynamic list.
3. Sort this list by common property.
4. Added pages with X.PagedList

Example code:

Models:

```
        private interface BaseInfo
        {
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }

        public class CompanyEvent : BaseInfo
        {
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }

        public class SummerEvent : BaseInfo
        {
            public bool IsActive { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public string MainPartner { get; set; }
        }

        public class Birthday : BaseInfo
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        }
```

Code

```
public IPagedList<dynamic> GetDynamicInfo(int pageNumber)
{
    int pageSize = 10;

    List<dynamic> dynamicList = new List<dynamic>();

    IQueryable<CompanyEvent> companyEvents = Employees.Select(a => new CompanyEvent()
            {
                Date = a.EventDate,
                Description = a.Description
            });
    IQueryable<SummerEvent> summerEvents = Employees.Select(a => new SummerEvent()
            {
                Date = a.StartEventDate,
                IsActive = a.IsActive,
                MainPartner = a.Partner.Name
            });
    IQueryable<Birthday> birthdays = Employees.Select(a => new Birthday()
            {
                Date = a.DateBorn,
                FirstName = a.FirstName,
                a.LastName = a.LastName
            });

    dynamicList.AddRange(companyEvents);
    dynamicList.AddRange(summerEvents);
    dynamicList.AddRange(birthdays);

    var sortedDynamicList = dynamicList.OrderBy(a => ((BaseInfo)a).Date).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    return sortedDynamicList;
}
```

Comment: It is a common beginners mistake to retreive a lot, then do filtering in the Programm. Do not do that. Do as much filtering, processing and especially pagination during the DB Query itself. Your C# code will never be able to beat the DB's performance and at best you only add a lot of wasted Networking time. | I am not quite sure how to do that with linq-to-entities (or if it can work at all). But depending on DBMS you could add a view that has all those values mathed out and combined.

Comment: @Christopher he is using `IQueryable` which will make filtering pagination happen in DB

Comment: You really want to generate an sql union. Which means you need to `.Select(...)` the same projection type, then you can `.Concat().Skip().Take()`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `ToPageList` that is bringing all the data in memory. You can use `Skip` and `Take` which will get translated to respective sql and do pagination on DB side like:

```
var sortedDynamicList = dynamicList
                      .OrderBy(a => ((BaseInfo)a).Date)
                      .Skip(pageNumber)
                      .Take(pageSize)
                      .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Secondly instead of using `IPagedList<dynamic>` you can use `IPagedList<BaseInfo>` that will also work same way.

### UPDATE:

As in this scenario data is getting loaded from different tables and even different columns in them, one possible way is to load them separately each page of them and then do sort and paging on those like:

```
IQueryable<CompanyEvent> companyEvents = Employees.Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize)
       .Select(a => new CompanyEvent()
        {
            Date = a.EventDate,
            Description = a.Description
        });

IQueryable<SummerEvent> summerEvents = Employees.Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize)
        .Select(a => new SummerEvent()
        {
            Date = a.StartEventDate,
            IsActive = a.IsActive,
            MainPartner = a.Partner.Name
        });

IQueryable<Birthday> birthdays = Employees.Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize)
        .Select(a => new Birthday()
        {
            Date = a.DateBorn,
            FirstName = a.FirstName,
            a.LastName = a.LastName
        });
```

and then do the following:

```
        dynamicList.AddRange(companyEvents);
        dynamicList.AddRange(summerEvents);
        dynamicList.AddRange(birthdays);
        var sortedDynamicList = dynamicList.OrderBy(a => ((BaseInfo)a).Date)
                                           .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

Comment: When i adding data to dynamic list:
dynamicList.AddRange(companyEvents);
dynamicList.AddRange(summerEvents);
 dynamicList.AddRange(birthdays);
all data already bringing in memory and i want to avoid this ...

Comment: @Librain yes that will bring them in memory, you can't do like that, you will need to query from three tables separately paged data and then sort them in memory and pick required data, or you will need to write sql query or stored procedure as your scenario is quite different than normal

Comment: @Librain i have updated the answer with one possible way to do it

Comment: thank you for your reply but there will be several problems. If i take certain part from table there no guarantee that this data will be in result because i sort by date and also there no way to get all pages count  ...

Comment: @Librain you need to rethink of your approach, it's made over complex currently